# Netsuite - create project from button in estimate

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a Worfklow on the estimate transaction with a button and the idea of this button is to activate a WorkflowActionScript type script in which it creates a project transaction, related to the estimate and taking the values of the estimate fields.

but when uploading the script to netsuite I get the following error: Fail to evaluate script: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":"ReferenceError: "currentRecord" is not defined.

```
/**
 *
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType WorkflowActionScript
 *
 */

require (['N/currentRecord'],

function createProject(){
    //get data from Est/Client to send to New Project record
    var EstRecord = currentRecord.get();
    var customer = EstRecord.getValue({ fieldId: 'entity'});
    if (!customer){alert('Cannot create a project since "Client" is not selected.');    return;}
    var title = EstRecord.getValue({fieldId: 'title'});


    //format new Project name.  Should be Customer Name Market Abbreviation "Service Work Order" Date
    var name = EstRecord.getText({fieldId: 'entity'});
    //var market = EstRecord.getValue({fieldId: 'custevent_ee_case_market'});

    //get date and format for title
    d = new Date();
    mon = d.getMonth() +1;
    day = d.getDate();
    year = d.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);
    var today = mon +'/'+ day +'/'+ year;
    var projectName = name+' '+' MS '+title+' '+today


    //create new project
    var newProject = record.create({
    type: record.Type.JOB,
    isDynamic: true,  //default is false
    });
    newProject.setValue({
    fieldId: 'custentity38',  //Project Type
    value: 1
    });
    newProject.setValue({
    fieldId: 'customform',
    value: 74
    });
    newProject.setValue({
    fieldId: 'companyname',
    value: projectName
    });
    newProject.setValue({
    fieldId: 'parent',
    value: customer
    });
    newProject.setValue({
    fieldId: 'projecttemplate',
    value: 1488
    });
    var newProjectId = newProject.save({
    enableSourcing: true, //default is false
    ignoreMandatoryFields: true  //default is false
    });

   
    alert('Done creating Project.');
    //refresh current page
    window.open('https://XXX.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/estimate.nl?id='+EstRecord.id);
    //display newly created project in a new tab
    window.open('https://XXX.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/project/project.nl?id='+newProjectId);
    } 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use `define` instead of `require` in an entry point
   script.  Change
   `require (['N/currentRecord'],`
   to
   `define (['N/currentRecord'],`.
2. The `define` function has the signature `define(id?, dependencies?, factory);`.  You don't have an `id` for this; that's ok, it's
   optional (and in fact doesn't make sense for a NetSuite entry point
   script).  You have listed your `dependencies` (or dependency) -
   `[N/currentRecord']`.  Now you need an anonymous `factory` function,
   and you need to pass in the dependenc[y|ies] as [a] parameter[s].
   Change

   ```
   define (['N/currentRecord'],

   function createProject(){
       ...
       } 
   )
   ```

   to

   ```
   define (['N/currentRecord'],
      function (currentRecord) {

      function createProject(){
         ...
      } 
   })
   ```

   or, using an arrow function as supported in the latest ECMAScript versions and SuiteScript 2.1

   ```
   define (['N/currentRecord'], currentRecord => {            
       function createProject(){
          ...    
       }   
   })
   ```

For more information on this pattern you can search "Asyncronous Module Definition" or go to [Understanding AMD & RequireJS](https://www.devbridge.com/articles/understanding-amd-requirejs/)